# Physical meaning of Damped Exponential Sinusoidal

Tags: friction, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, vibrations, dissipation

$$x(t)=A\sin(tf+p)e^{-dt}$$

The equation is used for damped exponential sinusoidal, if used for stress decomposition does it have any physical value, especially the exponential $d$?

Comment: You have asked this on two other SE sites and mention a device called an [Harmonograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonograph).  I am not clear what you mean by "stress decomposition" in this context.

Comment: What do the “gravitational-waves” and “stress-strain” tags have to do with this question?

Comment: d has a unit of 1 over time to compensate the t.

Comment: The exponential functions like Kohlrausch–Williams–Watt's (KWW) is used to find properties like dielectric properties, heat energy, dissipation of a material so on, basically from stress sinusoidal waves. So if above equation is applied to same stress sinusoidal, will it signify anything? especially changing exp-d values.

Answer (score 1):

The physical meaning of the damping exponential is that the oscillating system is losing energy, so the amplitude of the oscillations decreases. $1/d$ measures the timescale of this damping.